# Rails Devise Token Autentication Rspec JSON API testing session issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api, rspec, devise

I am building a JSON api using Ruby on Rails for a mobile application.
I have a random game function that works like such:

1. Player 1 requests random game.
2. Player 2 requests random game.
3. Game is now started since players make a pair.

This is done by the /games/random_game.json call.

The rspec test looks like such:

```
it "should start a random game" do
    post "/api/v1/games/random_game.json", 
      :token => player1.authentication_token,
      :game_type => "tictactoe"


    post "/api/v1/games/random_game.json", 
      :token => player2.authentication_token,
      :game_type => "tictactoe"

    parsed_body = JSON.parse(last_response.body)
    parsed_body.has_key?("gamestate").should == true
    end
```

What is expected:
First call should return status:success
Second call should return json of the new game

What happens:

First call returns status:success

Second call returns status:failed error:"Player cannot have two pending games of same type"

In the random game method i threw a print statement of the user. It is always player one.

In the random game method I thew a print statement of the params. It is posting TWO different tokens.

The worst part is if I make these same calls using CURL it succeeds.

Is something happening in Rspec to cache the user session??

Comment: How did you create the two users?

Comment: player1 = User.create ( { :nickname=>"player1", :udid=>"player1_udid" } )
 player1.ensure_authentication_token!
 player2 = User.create ( { :nickname=>"player2", :udid=>"player2_udid" } )
 player2.ensure_authentication_token!

Comment: They are two different users with two different authentication tokens

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out? I'm seeing the same issue. There's a bug somewhere and I'm going to track it down right now, unless you've figured it out and do not mind sharing :)

Answer (score 0):

You can stub the authentication token like this :

```
player1.stub(:authentication_token).and_return("test1234")
player2.stub(:authentication_token).and_return("test4321")
```

Comment: Thanks but that didnt solve my problem. Rails always recieves two different token variables BUT the current_user only returns the first user.

Comment: Do you use devise for your authentication?